# $(2n)$-regular graphs don't have bridges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $k$-regular graph where $k$ is even. I want to prove $G$ doesn't have a bridge. I was thinking I could prove by contradiction and assume that G has a bridge. But from there I have no idea where to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Remove the bridge, thereby disconnecting the graph. Then show that the sum of the degrees of the vertices in each of the new components is odd. Why is this impossible?

Comment: Is it impossible cause of the Handshaking Lemma where 2|E| = sum of degrees of vertices. But since the sum of degrees is odd, then it would never become 2|E|?

Comment: @Yekk: That’s right. So all you that you need to do now to complete the argument is explain why the sum of the degrees in each component must be odd.

Answer (score 0):

A $2k$-regular graph is Eulerian so removing an edge results in a graph with an Eulerian walk. You could also use the [2-factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-factor_theorem) to show that the endpoints of any edge a lie on a cycle and therefore there exist at least two paths between them.